# An error has occurred, Insuficient permission

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, permissions

I am using linux ubuntu 18.04 version , I want to install extension to google chrome, When I add extension I get the following error:

Chrome: `An error has occurred,Download interrupted,`

In download panel I see this error: `Failed Insuficient permission`

Here is screen short
[image]

Here is what I have tried :

1. Changing the location : didint work
2. Clear cache using google chrome clean cache also didnt work.
3. `sudo apt update` didnt work

What do I need to do to get rid of this stupidity error? thanks

Comment: Are you logged in as SU?

Comment: I am logged as normal user , how do I login  as su? though, right now if I want to install something I just type su ...... etc everything goes well

Comment: are you able to download another files from another resources?

Comment: Yes , only extension I cnt add